# Calculate number of words in Python

Tags: python, pandas

This is my sample dataset[image]

I need to create a new column "number of characters". This column should indicate the number of words in the queries. I tried to use this code,

```
df.words = [len(df.query.split()) for sentence in df.query]
```

but this error returns:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'query'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
df['words'] =df['query'].str.split().apply(len)
```

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'query':['asd vbg ffd','fd vv']})
df['words'] =df['query'].str.split().apply(len)
```

Then `df` is

```
    query       words
0   asd vbg ffd 3
1   fd vv       2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) what nice working with `None` and missing values also:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'query':['asd vbg ffd','fd vv', None, np.nan]})

df['words'] = df['query'].str.split().str.len()
print (df)
         query  words
0  asd vbg ffd    3.0
1        fd vv    2.0
2         None    NaN
3          NaN    NaN
```

---

```
df['words'] =df['query'].str.split().apply(len)
```

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: @RanTao This should be accepted answer as, even if any column's are empty, jezrael 's code will work.

Comment: @SRingne - Thank you.